# IONIC4 Background image is resized when keyboard is open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to set a background image to my login page, some basic stuff. But when one of the input is pressed and the keyboard is shown the image gets resized (to a small size)

My background image is sitting in a div tag, I tried putting the image in ion-content tag, tho it solves the keyboard issue but then the image gets zoomed in way too much. I tried using the ion-view tag but then I get the following error

> .... error: Template parse errors: 'ion-view' is not a known element:

Here's my html code (tho it's some basic stuff)

```
<div class="bg">
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(form)">

</form>

<ion-label ... ></ion-label> 
</div>
```

Here's my bg class:

```
.bg{
padding-bottom: 0 !important;
background-image: url('../../assets/lock.png') !important;
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: cover !important;
background-size: cover !important;
background-position: center; 
background-attachment: fixed;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with changing some attributes in my bg class:

```
.bg{
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    background-image: url('../../assets/lock.png') !important;
    height: 100% auto !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
ion-content { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. the other solutions here still resulted in some jumps

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to work for me without any problems.

First find your AndroidManifest.xml (platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

In there find this line:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

In it change the android:windowSoftInputMode value to "adjustPan".

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to target the `ion-content` tag.

Looking back at a project I did that had a gradient background, I used this:

```
@mixin linearGradient($top, $bottom){
  background: $top; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  $top 0%, $bottom 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,$top), color-stop(100%,$bottom)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  $top 0%,$bottom 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  $top 0%,$bottom 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  $top 0%,$bottom 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  $top 0%,$bottom 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

ion-content {
  @include linearGradient($brand-beer, $brand-darkbeer);
}
```

And didn't notice any display issues. So you can probably just put your bg snippet into an `ion-content` sass line like this:

```
ion-content {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    background-image: url('../../assets/lock.png') !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I'm not sure where you got `ion-view` from. A quick search seems like this hasn't been in Ionic since v1. It has gone through some major changes over the versions so you should always make sure that the help you are reading is for the version of Ionic that you're working with, otherwise you will get even more stuck.

Comment: Regarding the ion-view point, yeah I felt a little dump trying to use something long gone, I will try to be more careful next time. Now, regarding the ion-content point, I tried the same exact thing you advised and it did not work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

By adding this to the config.xml should fix this issue, without css tricks:

```xml
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
</edit-config>
```

If this not works, try removing/adding the android platform after adding the code above to the config.xml:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

or changing the "file" attribute to:
`file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"` and rebuilding the app.